# MRTK Bounds Control to Scale an Object in Fixed Position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mrtk

I'm attempting to use MRTKs (2.8.2) bounds control ([Documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/ux-building-blocks/bounds-control)) to scale an object by hand with a fixed position in world space (with Unity 2021.3.11). Bounds control scales the object in such a way, that the object follows the users hand when scaling, meaning also the position of the object is adjusted. I want to modify this behaviour in such a way that the object's center is only moving in the y axis (thus standing on the ground while scaling).

Applying the MoveAxisConstraint via the constraint manager doesn't do anything. I would like to inherit bounds control or duplicate it to modify the scaling method (private void TransformTarget(HandleType)), but 1. relevant methods are private and 2. many methods and classes like e.g. the interface IBoundsTargetProvider are internal and therefore "inaccessible due to its protection level" ([Error CS0122](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-messages/cs0122?f1url=%3FappId%3Droslyn%26k%3Dk(CS0122))).

I could copy all classes with relevant internal properties and set them to public, but that doesn't seem to be a nice solution to me. Or I might have to abandon bounds control and write my own script.
Do you know another approach to this problem?

Comment: When I needed to adjust the behavior I ended up with the latter and copied the class and then started o overwrite the parts I didn't like ^^

Comment: @derHugo Thanks, it's very interesting to read how others solve these kind of problems. That's also what I mostly did in the past, but in this case the class has about 1500 lines of code, which all seems to be somewhat important and have dependencies.

Comment: yeah .. I didn't say it was the most desirable solution .. back then (2 years ago) it was the best option - quick an dirty